# Не запускается Kafdrop

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Не запускается kafdrop через docker.
docker-compose.yml:

```html
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    container_name: kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:9092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M"
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"
```

Текст ошибки:

```html
 2023-10-20 12:17:55.228  INFO ${sys:PID} [           main] k.Kafdrop$EnvironmentSetupListener       : Initializing JAAS config
2023-10-20 15:17:55 2023-10-20 12:17:55.242  INFO ${sys:PID} [           main] k.Kafdrop$EnvironmentSetupListener       : Env: null
2023-10-20 15:17:55 2023-10-20 12:17:55.499  INFO 1 [kground-preinit] o.h.v.i.u.Version                        : HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.1.Final
2023-10-20 15:17:55 2023-10-20 12:17:55.567  INFO 1 [           main] o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger                  : Starting Kafdrop v4.0.0 using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 1 (/kafdrop-4.0.0/kafdrop-4.0.0.jar started by root in /)
2023-10-20 15:17:55 2023-10-20 12:17:55.580  INFO 1 [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-20 15:17:51 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2023-10-20 15:17:58 2023-10-20 12:17:58.618 ERROR 1 [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed
2023-10-20 15:17:58 
2023-10-20 15:17:58 java.lang.StackOverflowError
2023-10-20 15:17:58     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
2023-10-20 15:17:58     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
2023-10-20 15:17:58     at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
2023-10-20 15:17:58     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
```

Увеличивал стек, ошибка остается